# How were const and reference types initialized before initializer lists?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, initializer-list

The Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2013 states about "initializing lists" in C++ that:

*"With class members that are const or reference types, you have no choice as to how they are initialized. The only way is to use a member initializer list in a constructor. Assignment within the body of a constructor will not work."*

My Visual Studio 2012 express did not compile the initializer list so I was confused at first, then I realized that it is not supported in it.

My question is how did people initialize *const or reference types* before initializer lists since the book says that there is no other way besides using initializer lists?

Comment: You're confusing [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (read small note under the second link).

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing two separate terms. That's OK; they're named almost identically.

There are initializer lists (which I call "braced-init-lists" precisely to avoid this confusion). These are `{}` delimited sequences of items which are used to initialize values. If the items are of the same type, they can be converted into a `std::intializer_list`. This was a C++11 addition.

Then, there is the member initialization list in a constructor. That's this syntax:

```
TypeName(params)
  : member1(...)
  , member2(...)
{
  /*constructor code*/
}
```

That's been in C++ since C++98/03. The member initialization list is how you initialize `const` members and reference types.

Comment: Also known as the *ctor-initializer*.

Answer (score 1):

The Horton quote talks about the [Member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) which is a C++98 feature.

This is unrelated to `std::initializer_list` and [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) with the `type name {stuff...};` syntax which both are indeed C++11 features.